# Snakemake: Cluster multiple jobs together

Tags: hpc, snakemake

I have a pretty simple `snakemake` pipeline that takes an input file does three subsequent steps to produce one output. Each individual job is very quick. Now I want to apply this pipeline to >10k files on an SGE cluster. Even if I use `group` to have one job for each three rules per input file, I would still submit >10k cluster jobs. Is there a way to instead submit limited number of cluster jobs (lets say 100) and distribute all tasks equally between them?

An example would be something like

```
rule A:
        input: {prefix}.start
        output: {prefix}.A
        group "mygroup"

rule B:
        input: {prefix}.A
        output: {prefix}.B
        group "mygroup"

rule C:
        input: {prefix}.B
        output: {prefix}.C
        group "mygroup"

rule runAll:
        input: expand("{prefix}.C", prefix = VERY_MANY_PREFIXES)
```

and then run it with
`snakemake --cluster "qsub  <some parameters>" runAll`

Comment: I am not aware of any built-in solution. In that past, I just merged them into single rule in such scenarios.

Comment: Here is a hacky implementation by Rasmus Ågren https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/967/batch-together-small-jobs-in-cluster. I've seen Johannes köster mention on several different pages that this is definitely something he is planning to implement, but unfortunately for now you are stuck with sth hacky like this

Comment: Just found more discussion on this: https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/851/stacking-small-independent-jobs-into-the

Answer (score 0):

You could process all the 10k files in the same rule using a for loop (not sure if this is what Manavalan Gajapathy has in mind). For example:

```
rule A:
    input:
        txt= expand('{prefix}.start', prefix= PREFIXES),
    output:
        out= expand('{prefix}.A', prefix= PREFIXES),
    run:
        io= zip(input.txt, output.out)
        for x in io:
            shell('some_command %s %s' %(x[0], x[1]))
```

and the same for rule B and C.

Look also at snakemake [local-rules](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#local-rules)

Comment: No, I was suggesting combing rules A, B and C into a single rule. That is `input` for combined rule would be `{prefix}.start` and `output` be `{prefix}.C`. And, +1 to `localrules`.

Comment: Thanks, but neither solves the problem. In this solution all jobs (combined to one) would have to run on one machine (either remote or local) which is not the aim. And when combining the rules A-C to one rule you still need to run 10k (or however many) independent jobs

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of would be to declare rules A, B, and C to be local rules, so that they run in the main snakemake job instead of being submitted as a job. Then you can break up your runAll into batches:

```
rule runAll1:
        input: expand("{prefix}.C", prefix = VERY_MANY_PREFIXES[:1000])

rule runAll2:
        input: expand("{prefix}.C", prefix = VERY_MANY_PREFIXES[1000:2000])

rule runAll3:
        input: expand("{prefix}.C", prefix = VERY_MANY_PREFIXES[2000:3000])

...etc
```

Then you submit a snakemake job for runAll1, another for runAll2, and so on. You do this fairly easily with a bash loop:

```
for i in {1..10}; do sbatch [sbatch params] snakemake runAll$i; done;
```

Another option which would be more scalable than creating multiple runAll rules would be to have a helper python script that does something like this:

```
import subprocess

for i in range(0, len(VERY_MANY_PREFIXES), 1000):
    subprocess.run(['sbatch', 'snakemake'] + ['{prefix}'.C for prefix in VERY_MANY_PREFIXES[i:i+1000]])
```